# Storing methods in a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a card game similar to Magic: the Gathering where there is a stack system for effects to resolve. E.g. I cast draw a card and my opponent can respond with his own draw effect. Then the last effect that entered the stack will trigger and so on until all effects in the stack resolve. I thought the best way to handle this would to have a list store effects as methods and then have a new method resolve and remove them from last to first. Is this possible or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not store the actual methods but rather objects.

For instance you could make an interface `IAction` with the function `Run`.

Then create a class for each action implementing `IAction`.

Then where you maintain the MTG equivalent of the 'stack' you have an `IEnumerable<IAction>` to which you add the instances.

Does this make sense?

EDIT: I wrote a bit of code to illustrate the idea

EDIT2: Use Stack data structure instead of LinkedList

```cs
interface IEffect
{
    void Resolve();
}

class SomeEffect : IEffect
{
    public void Resolve()
    {
        // do something
    }
}

class EffectStack
{
    private Stack<IEffect> _effectStack = new Stack<IEffect>();

    public void Add(IEffect effect)
    {
        _effectStack.Push(effect);
    }

    public void ResolveAll()
    {
        while (_effectStack.Count)
        {
            _effectStack.Pop().Resolve();
        }
    }
}

class Client
{
    private EffectStack _effectStack = new();
    
    public void Run()
    {
        _effectStack.Add(new SomeEffect());
        
        _effectStack.ResolveAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Im trying to wrap my head around this. I understand the first part. I would create an Interface and have a class per card ability and the code in the run function. I am not sure how the IEnumerable<IAction> part works(this is quite new to me).

Comment: I wrote a bit of code to illustrate the idea

Comment: Thank you for pushing me in the right direction. LinkedList is completely new to me but I can see how it works based off the code that you have wrote. I believe after a bit of studying Ill be able to use this solve my problem.

Comment: Why not use an actual `Stack<IEffect>` or a `Queue<IEffect>` though?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), often used in the generic form of [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-6.0) with different number of generic parameters. These can be collected in a list and called one at a time. There is also [Multi-delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-combine-delegates-multicast-delegates) that essentially is a list of delegates, with some special syntax to call all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do that more easily.

As long is you just want to store method references in a collection in memory, there is no problem to do it. You just have to define the signature you want for those methods, and define a delegate for that.

Also if you want a collection designed to retrieve the elements from last to first, that's exactly what Stack do (LIFO = Last In, First Out).

Here is a simple exemple:

```
public class Card
{
  //...
}

public delegate void Effect(Card card);
Stack<Effect> EffectsStack;
```

Comment: Then you have 2 options: either you add more parameters in the Effect delegate, to tell the method what kind of effect you want. 

Or, as suggested above, you consider using an interface and different classes implementing that interface. 

My suggestion here was to give you the simplest way to answer your question. But for a more elaborated application, having classes instead of just simple methods is the clean way to do it.